# Logstash Capture http response from http output plugin

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I have wrote a logstash program to post some message to URL. there is no error from logstash but i wanted to know is there a way to capture response from the url what we post using http output plugin ?

```
   output {
      stdout {
      codec => json_lines
      }
      http{
          url => "Rest URl"
          http_method => "post"
          format => "json"
          headers => {"Authorization" => "%{pass}"}
      }
   }
```

I had gone through the documentation but i didnot find anything realted to it.
Forgive me if it is dumb question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no dumb questions ;-)

Unfortunately, there's no way to get any response from the `http` output plugin. It will only log an error if you get an HTTP response whose status code is `<200` or `>299` or if there's an exception during the call (e.g. because the remote server is down).

The reason it is done that way is because there would be no way to use the response anyway since outputs are the last step in any Logstash pipeline and outputs do not communicate with each other.

What you need is an HTTP filter plugin, one that executes after inputs and before outputs. You're lucky because one such exists and is described at https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/3489

The elastic/logstash folks have recognized a need for this and are working on a more [generic lookup filter](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/5221) than just for HTTP.

Comment: thanks for answering .. question is if i have BAD request Error code which is 400 will that also be logged ? I want to know if the request failed due to BAD request .

Comment: Yes, as mentioned above, if you get an HTTP response with status 400 it will get logged by Logstash.

Comment: I dint tried the filter part but the responses were working as expected. Thanks for the help .. sorry for the late reply .